# SQL Login for SSRS Reports require EXECUTE permissions?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, ssrs, reporting

Recently my team did a `SSRS` report deployment.The reporting server was installed in application server and it was pointed to database server.I don't know why we do like that?Probably to avoid load on the database server.

Usually the team just deploy `.rdl` files to the reporting server and it usually works.But recently when the team did `SSRS` reports deployment,the reports was not running when checked.
So on checking at the report manager url,i can see the  deployed report.
Later it was identified that the SQL Report login requires `EXECUTE` permission.
Till now no other reports required that permission,this new report asked for this permission.Why did it happen?
I know that EXECUTE permission is required to run the sp's.
Is it necessary to give `EXECUTE` for `SSRS SQL logins`

Additional Detail : The fix given was to give `EXECUTE` permission for the user.But what confuses me is that ,all of a sudden the `SSRS` sql login requires `EXECUTE` permission.For none of the other reports which runs of sp's never asked for `EXECUTE` permission.

Comment: You can create a report/fill in parameter box from stored procedure and this seems to be your case. In this case the login has to have EXECUTE permission, at least on the procedure that was used in that report

Comment: The fix given was to grant `EXECUTE` permission for the user.But what confuses me is ,all of a sudden the `SSRS` sql login requires `EXECUTE` permission.For none of the other reports which runs of sp's never asked for `EXECUTE` permission.

Comment: Are the reports using a shared datasource?  Are you using a specific login or windows authentication/pass through?

Comment: @Jonathan.I am using a specific SQL Login.What do you mean by shared data source.The reporting server is configured in the application server and pointed to database server.